# What to do with questions that are answered with no answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

This question [Excel not creating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553649/excel-not-creating)
has no answers, but was resolved in the comments to the question.

Should I write a comment and encourage the user to answer it him/her/it self?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the answer came from another user, then ask him to put his comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it.

If the answer came from the OP, he should answer it in the form of an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, or post yourself the answer.

The important thing is for questions to get answers, it doesn't matter who posts it, or where it comes from.