# How do we prod users who have answered their own questions to post an answer and accept it?

Tags: feature-request, self-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Promoting comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers)

In trawling through the *Unanswered Questions* page, I've come across more than a few questions where the original poster has answered his or her own question, either by editing the question itself or by posting it as a comment. Here's an example: [Nodejs - .node_libraries/ for www-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943384/nodejs-node-libraries-for-www-data).

Currently, there's no way to get the user to make that answer an actual answer as recognised by Stack Overflow and accept it. I'd like to see a way to prod either the user or a moderator into moving that answer into the answers section and accepting it, taking it off the Unanswered Questions page.

Comment: And for good measure: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44693/what-to-do-with-questions-that-are-answered-with-no-answers http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/force-accepted-answers-on-questions-by-inactive-users http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature

Comment: @random: Apologies. I did search for possible duplicates but none of those came up.

Comment: Several years later, dozens of other users (including me) are still trying to debate this issue. I really hope SO staff will consider the idea eventually. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354584/534406