# How to encourage answers to be posted on obviously resolved questions

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I find a lot of questions, particularly on SO, with no answer but a long trail of comments which once read, it becomes apparent it has been answered. Often with a comment by the OP saying something like "thanks that worked". It makes it a much longer search when looking for an answer.

Posting an answer which covers the content of the comments is considered a good practice, but OP seem disinclined to do (refer [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a?rq=1) )

To encourage OP behavour my proposal is to specifically give OP rep if they post the answer to their question when its
   resolved with no other answers in order to complete the
   documentation.

I trust I am not asking something that already has an established approach.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a?rq=1

Comment: `I trust I am not asking something that already has an established approach` not really, but you are asking something that has been discussed to death.  Comments are comments, answers are answers.  Now a comment might give the OP enough of a hint to find the solution on his own, but rarely are they worthy of being an actual answer.  The solution is encouraging the OP to post their answer or encourage the commenter to expand their comment into an answer.

Comment: My real point, which I will take the blame for a badly phrased question, and I agree and accept that Q-117251 is a widely accepted approach, is that despite all this the OP is seldom posting their own answer.  And that is the behavior that should be encouraged.  Mr psubsee2003 - the size of the discussion is not a measure of the existence or quality of a solution.  I firmly believe that OP should get a small rep bump for posting their own answer on an answer:0 closed:0 question.  Thereby encouraging them to take out the fluff from unanswered questions section.

Answer (score 2):

In that scenario, it might be good to encourage the original question poster to provide their own answer and accept it with the code/solution to their question by leaving a comment?

If I asked a question and got it worked out through the help of comments, I would post a complete solution explaining what worked and the like as well as giving credit to the folks in the comment trail.

Comment: That is great @Fluffeh, it is exactly what I expect.  But we see so little of this from the OP.

Comment: I always ask the OP to try and summarize what they did to get whatever to work and hopefully include info from comments that helped them get there.