# What should we do when getting an answer in comments?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, answers

What do we have to do when our question is resolved in the comments? Should we delete the question, or just let it appear as unanswered eternally, or there is another solution?

**Edit:**

I have read the question [What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-to-do-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-instead-of-a) but i think that the answer given by Kate Gregory would be also useful to the community as it suggests another solution which is not suggested in the first question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not add an answer that expands a little on the comment (include some sample code, or links to references) and that way the question is no longer unanswered. If it's your question, you can even accept the answer to indicate that you are sure it works.

If you feel guilty that you will get rep for this, you can @reply the commenter saying "make that an answer and I'll accept it" and then only add your own answer if a certain amount of time goes by without the commenter doing that.

Comment: If you *really* don't want rep for it, convert your answer to Community Wiki, as suggested in this answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments.