# Checkmark option appears to be missing - can't accept answer!

Tags: support, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I signed up yesterday and asked a question on StackOverflow - and received an answer within about an hour. But I can't find anyway to 'accept' it. I realize there's supposed to be checkmarks, but they're not showing. Am I missing something totally obvious?! I've tried two different browsers (Chrome and Firefox) and turning off the adblocker on my Chrome. But still nothing! Here's the view I currently have of my question and comments: [image: enter image description here!]

Comment: You can only accept answers; not comments. No one posted on actual answer.

Comment: It seems like your question was answered as a comment, not as an actual answer post. In that case, you can find what to do at [What should be done with questions that have been self-resolved as a comment instead of an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62478097/4751173) may have been 'solved' in the comments underneath the question, but those are not 'answers' in Stack Exchange terminology, e.g. as mentioned in the Help Center article [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). You can only accept 'real' answers; you'll have to ask Michael to post their solution as an answer before you can accept it.